# How to call a method in views.py automatically after updating/modifying the table in Django?

Tags: python, email, django-models, django-views

I am building a web based application, in which i need to send the notification to registered user by `E-mail` after updating or modifying some value in tables.

I have a `model.py`:

```
class ProileComment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
    user = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=True)
```

Method in `views.py`

```
def send_email(request):
   ##
```

According to my problem if `ProfileComment` model will update then it should automatically called the `send_email` method. So that user will get the notification about the changes in database. How should i proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use django [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/)!!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/

They allow you to register a signal listener.  perhaps pre_save signal would best suite your needs?   Whenever something is saved anywhere in your app your signal will be called, and you can make a decision based on the model or whatever other conditions you need.

Or if you only want to send_email for that one model only you could override the `save` method!

```
class ProfileComment(models.Model):


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      # send email?
      super(ProfileComent, self, *args, **kwargs) # make sure to call parent!
```